# Android - file.exists() returns true for /mnt/sdcard folder, even though SDCard is unmounted? - Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, sd-card

I unmounted the SD card by renaming the SDCard file (sdcard.img - located in .Android folder) for the emulator.

But my application's f.exists() still returns true for the root folder of the sd card - /mnt/sdcard (even though it technically shouldn't be there).

How can this be possible?

Edit: it returns false for files located under /mnt/sdcard/something. But it returns true for the root folder /mnt/sdcard - that's what's confusing me.

Comment: Are you sure it is not still also in `/mnt/sdcard` ?

Comment: Try it in a real device emulator plays funny when it comes with sdcard.

Comment: What makes you think that renaming the external storage image file will "unmount" external storage in the emulator?

Comment: What is wrong? /mnt/sdcard exists but nothing is mounted there?

Comment: No, when I do a list of /mnt files, a folder called sdcard isn't listed there. Yet, when I call f.exists() on /mnt/sdcard, it returns true. It's contradictory because /mnt/sdcard folder doesn't exists when my sd card is unmounted. Maybe it's a bug or I may have misunderstood the api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maybe it's a bug or I may have misunderstood the api.

Neither. The emulator simply created a new external storage image. You have not "unmounted" anything.

Comment: Well, can you explain then why does new File ("/mnt/sdcard/LOST.DIR").exists(); return false then? I think I did unmount it, because if it was still mounted, that DIR (and a few other default ones) would exist. I emphasized how the root sd card folder exists(), yet the sdcard/... other files do not.

Comment: @Tool: "Well, can you explain then why does new File ("/mnt/sdcard/LOST.DIR").exists(); return false then?" -- because your newly-created external storage image is empty. "I think I did unmount it" -- offer any proof of any documentation anywhere that backs up your claim.

Comment: My proof was the fact that new File("/mnt/sdcard").listFiles() returns null. Which means it's empty. Yet the folder itself, /mnt/sdcard exists, which is what's bothering me (should it if it's unmounted?). You can try it yourself on the emulator, I don't really have to proove it.

Comment: @Tool: "Which means it's empty" -- it is empty. "should it if it's unmounted?" -- it is not unmounted. Your old external storage image, that you renamed, was replaced by a new external storage image, and that new external storage image is empty and mounted.